# Thinking of a Continuous function

Tags: calculus

While I was writing a proof of some theorem I need to think of a continuous function like this:
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x(x+1)^{2}} & 0<x\leq 100\\
S & x=0
\end{cases}$$

Is is possible to put something in $S$ so $F$ will be continuous

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: $F(0)=\lim_{x\to0}1/x(x+1)^2$ is required to ensure continuity.

Comment: I think it will be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** What is $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x(x+1)^2}$? What must $S$ be equal to in order to ensure continuity? What happens if $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x(x+1)^2}$ is unbounded?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Note that  as x approaches $0$ from the right in  $$F(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x(x+1)^{2}} & 0<x\leq 100\\
S & x=0
\end{cases}$$ $F(x)$ grows without bound, so no real number will make it continuous at $x=0$